# Deploy ElasticBeanstalk environment using ClourdFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have the following CF template to deploy an EB env:

```
Resources:

  EBEC2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'ec2.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker'
      RoleName: 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role'


  EBServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkService'
      RoleName: 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role'

  EBApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: 'Freyja'
      Description: 'Freyja EB Application'

  EBAppVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: EBApplication
      Description: 'App version'
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::ImportValue:
                  Fn::Sub: 'S3MainBucket'
        S3Key: 'python.zip'

  EBEnv:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: EBApplication
      Description: 'Freyja main environment'
      EnvironmentName: 'Freyja'
      SolutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.4 running Python 3.7'
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: 'InstanceType'
          Value: 't2.nano'
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: 'IamInstanceProfile'
          Value: !Ref EBEC2Role
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment'
          OptionName: 'ServiceRole'
          Value: !Ref EBServiceRole
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: EBAppVersion
```

However, I keep getting an error while creating it in CF:

> Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state

I have been through lots of documentation and can't seem to find the cause of this. Keep in mind that the idea is to deploy this in a brand new account, which is why I'm creating the roles in the template, besides a separate CF template to create an S3 bucket, there's nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `IamInstanceProfile` should be **instance profile**, not role. So you could add it as follows:

```
  EBInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties: 
      Roles: 
        - !Ref EBEC2Role
```

Then:

```
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: 'IamInstanceProfile'
          Value: !Ref EBInstanceProfile
```